# Given that no yellow balls were chosen, what is the probability that there are exactly $2$ blue balls chosen?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I'm struggling with this problem.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Six balls are to be randomly chosen from $9$ blue, $9$ yellow and $14$ green balls.  Given that no yellow balls were chosen, what is the probability that there are exactly $2$ blue balls chosen?

I was thinking the answer is:

$$\frac{\binom{9}{2} \binom{14}{4}}{\binom{32}{6}}$$

but this isn't right and I really don't know how else to approach it.

Comment: How many choices of six non-yellow balls are there?  How many of those choices have exactly $2$ blue balls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @lulu -- all of these problems boil down to counting.

You correctly identified that there are $32 \choose 6$ ways to chose a set of 6 balls without replacement. However, we are told no yellow balls were chosen, so we can restrict our denominator to just the other two colors.

$$N = {23 \choose 6}$$

Of these, there are only ${9 \choose 2}{14 \choose 4}$ ways to select exactly 2 blue balls.

So you have the numerator correct, but since they used "given no yellow balls were chosen" we needed to adjust the denominator.